# stop joomla 1.5 loading jquery twice

Tags: joomla1.5

i have a custom joomla template which i load jquery in using the normal `<script></script>`  tages.  I have installed a plugin which also loads jquery, meaning that jquery is being loaded twice.  the plug in is only loaded on a few pages but i require jquery on every page so can't take it out the template.  what is the best way to stop it loading jquery twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this javascript code///

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {   
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
   script = document.createElement('script'); 
   script.id = 'jQuery'; 
   script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
   script.src = 'js/jquery.js'; 
   head.appendChild(script); 
} else { 
    // jQuery is loaded already need not include it...

}
```

typeOf operator checks if the jQuery object already exists if it does not exist then create a script element and append it to head of the html.